# Get first byte on an Integer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the first byte of an integer value in SQL Server?

In C#, I can do it easily using the `BitConverter`:

```
int x = 383;
var firstByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(x)[0];
Console.WriteLine(x);

// Expected Result: 127
```

How can I get same value in SQL Server query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT value % 256;`.

Comment: Yup. This is an answer to.

Comment: @TimRoberts - In 50% of the possible cases that will give the wrong answer. https://dbfiddle.uk/LbZCoeHn

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got alternate help from ChatGPT.

```
DECLARE @num INT;
SET @num = 383;
SELECT @num & 0xFF AS FirstByte; -- Expected result is 127
```

But I dont know the theory behind the query.

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND operator.  It only returns 1 where both sides are 1.  Since 0xFF has 1s only in the lowest 8 bits, the result will be the lowest 8 bits of @num.  That's the same as `% 256`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first byte, you can run it through a data type cast. Like so:

```sql
declare @i int = 383;
select cast(@i as binary(1));
```

If you need to have *that* as 127 (which in SQL is some sort of numeric data type), cast the result of the binary cast to tinyint (or whatever you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i int = 383;
select cast(cast(@i as binary(1)) as int);
```